# dyld: Symbol not found: _$s7SwiftUI12ViewModifierP14_viewListCount6inputs4bodySiSgAA01_cfG6InputsV_AgIXEtFZTq

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, dyld

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _$s7SwiftUI12ViewModifierP14_viewListCount6inputs4bodySiSgAA01_cfG6InputsV_AgIXEtFZTq
  Referenced from: /Users/naveenmadhan/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1E02E6B9-44B6-4714-8512-CCB2CDA4C294/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/C62A5372-0E34-4A0C-9080-524529DF4C9C/Instructor.app/Instructor
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/SwiftUI.framework/SwiftUI
 in /Users/naveenmadhan/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1E02E6B9-44B6-4714-8512-CCB2CDA4C294/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/C62A5372-0E34-4A0C-9080-524529DF4C9C/Instructor.app/Instructor
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries
DYLD_SHARED_CACHE_DIR=/Users/naveenmadhan/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Caches/dyld/20C69/com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-1.17A844
DYLD_ROOT_PATH=/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 13.1.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/naveenmadhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Instructor-cisqprshyexzidddmftwcbwdqzde/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator:/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 13.1.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/introspection
DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 13.1.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 13.1.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 13.1.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDD
(lldb)
```

[[image: Here's the screenshot]

The app builds but crashed after launch screen. The simulator ver is iOS 13.1 
But, it was working like a charm in iOS14. 
XCode ver is 12.

- Tried Cleaning Build Folder, Deleted Derived Data.

P.S. Also crash occurs in AppStore ver on iOS13 Phones.

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same issue... A different symbol that cannot be found, but same issue where it works on iOS 14 but fails on iOS 13 simulators.

Comment: This isn't a solution, but a workaround is that after the app crashed, I could still kill the debugging session in Xcode, relaunch the app on the simulator and it would run fine.